# curl is not working on my production server

Tags: php, curl

```
$url="http://nis.com/smsapi.asp?mobnum=".$umobile."&uid=*****&pswd=*****&msg=HI%20".$firstname."%2C%20THANKS%20FOR%20REGISTERING";

            $curl_handle = curl_init(); 
            curl_setopt( $curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10 ); 
            curl_setopt( $curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 ); 
            curl_setopt( $curl_handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1 ); 
            curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt( $curl_handle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1 ); 
            curl_setopt( $curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,$url ); 
            $buffer = curl_exec( $curl_handle ); 
            //print_r( curl_getinfo ( $curl_handle ) );
            echo("sfsf = ".$buffer );
}
```

there was a form , when the user enter the values like NAME . PHONE AND MAIL . after that using post request I took the mobile no and name from the post use it in my $url
When i on my localhost server it will send me the message but when i put it on my production server it shows no error and it will not send me the message

Note :the above link is a dummy link

Comment: Have you enabled [`error reporting?`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6575502/1003917) ?

Comment: Most probably missing the curl extension or it's not enabled in your php.ini. Check your phpinfo() output for this extension and enable some more error output.

Comment: yes i have but Its not showing me any error

Comment: You didn't use `curl_error()` to check for connection errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try to activate CURL functions in your production server 
Generally curl functions are desactivated in servers

Comment: this is my 2nd time I am using curl on my server so It was working on my 1st time , I guess there is a problem in my code only